# Some url with same structure but different value not working on live

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am modifying a website using `codeigniter 1.7.2`. And downloading an excel file. In that a url like below

```
http://my-website.com/folder/index.php/controller/function/46/2/20160630/confirmed/null/null/
```

**showing error like below in chrome**

[image]

**And the error for same page in firefox is**

[image]

**The redirection code is**

```
var val1 = window.parent.$("#id1").val();
var val2 = window.parent.$("#id2").val();
var val3 = window.parent.$("#id3").val();
var val4 = window.parent.$("#id4").val();
var val5 = window.parent.$("#id5").val();
if(val4 == ''){
    val4 = 'null';
}
if(val5 == ''){
    val5 = 'null';
}

window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/function/<?php echo $value ?>/'+val1+'/'+val2+'/confirmed/'+val3+'/'+val4+'/'+val5;
```

**If there any empty value, then I explicitly add character "null", So that the url structure will not break.**

I couldn't find what the error is. It seems like some server issues. Is it so? **The url with same structure producing result too**. Please guide me to det rid of this. Any  help could be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file on server, also, if mod_rewrite is enabled on server?

Comment: @Pupil, No. Nothing like that is there in the server.

Comment: can you show your code how you are generating this URL?

Comment: show complete code from where `val3`, `val4` etc coming

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, Updated query with those details

Comment: plz make your question completely clear & more precised. provide your CI's method whhere you write code for downloading XL file. do you think there enough info in your question to answer?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, I didn't provide that because it is not at all entering to that controller itself wen this error occurs.

Comment: In your conditions add `if( val4 == '' || val4 == undefined ){`. Same as for `val5`. Note that `'null' !== null` so results could be unpredictible if `null` is expected.